# SQL Server 2008 trigger error remove

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a trigger in SQL Server 2008

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ITEM_UOM_DELETE] ON
   [dbo].[ITEM_UOM] INSTEAD OF DELETE
   AS
      declare @rowc int
      set @rowc = (select count(*) from stock, deleted where 
      item = deleted.itemcode and uom = DELETED.MAINUNIT AND DOCTYPE <> 'OP')
         if @rowc > 0
         begin
           raiserror('Unit is in Use Cannot Delete', 16, 1)
           rollback transaction
         end
```

on execution of this trigger it gives the error output

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ITEM_UOM_DELETE, Line 11
>   Unit is in Use Cannot Delete
>   Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

I want the defined error only

> *Unit is in Use Cannot Delete*

How to remove the error 'The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.' ?

Comment: I have done this by removing 

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ITEM_UOM_DELETE] ON
[dbo].[ITEM_UOM] INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

declare @rowc int
select @rowc=count(*) from stock

if @rowc <= 0
begin
deleted uom from [ITEM_UOM] uom inner join deleted on uom.item = deleted.itemcode 
and uom.MAINUNIT = DELETED.MAINUNIT where uom.DOCTYPE <> 'OP'
end
else
begin
raiserror('Unit is in Use Cannot Delete', 16, 1)
end

end
```